# Keep logged in between reloads - Firebase (Sign in with Google)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

**How do you keep a user logged in with Sign in with Google between reloads?**

Here is my login function (Firebase):

```
    const loginWithGoogle = async () => {
        try {
            const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
            const res = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
            $user = res.user;
            $isLoggedIn = true;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Although `$isLoggedIn` and the `$user` object save to LocalStorage (I'm using SvelteJS), the user does not actually stay logged in after reloading.

After reloading, admin users are no longer able to write to the database and I get the error `firestore: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions`.

(Here are my firestore rules)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if (request.auth != null && (request.auth.uid == "someAdminID" || request.auth.uid == "otherAdminID"));
    }
  }
```

**How would I stay logged in after reloading? Or is there some way to automatically log in again if the user had not previously logged out?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most browser environments Firebase automatically persists the user credentials in local storage, and restores them when the app/page reloads. This requires it to make a call to the server however, a.o. to check if the account was disabled, and thus it isn't completed right away when the page loads.

To react to when the authentication state is restored (or otherwise changes), you'll want to use an auth state listener as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
    //  This is where you can also query the database as the user for the first time
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize Firebase automatically kept user credentials in localStorage.